# How to use Manipulate for the variable $z$ in the given ContourPlot of three functions?

Tags: plotting, manipulate, multivalued

I have these three functions (two of them 2-variables, and one is 3-variables)
$$\{\quad f:=f(x,y)\quad,\quad  g:=g(x,y)\quad,\quad h:=h(x,y,z) \quad\}$$

I would like to have  `ContourPlot` of these three functions for the variables $(x,y)$, I can do this for a fixed value of $z$ in the third function, but I need a more general result. How can I have  `ContourPlot` of these functions using  `Manipulate` when $z$ is not fixed and varies in the interval $(0,5)$?

```
f := -(-3 + x)^2 Cos[(2/3 + x) (\[Pi] - y) ] + 5 (1 + x)^2 Cos[(2/3 - x)] Sin[\[Pi] (2/3 + x)];
g := -(3 + x)^2 Sin[\[Pi] (2/3 + x)] Sin[(2/3 - x) ] + 5 (-1 + x)^2  Sin[(2/3 + x) (\[Pi] - y)];
h := 4 (-4 + x)^2 Cos[1/6 (\[Pi] - 6 x z)] - (-4 + x^2)^2 (Sin[x (2 \[Pi] - z)] +2 Cos[2 x (\[Pi] - y)] ) + (5 + x^2)^2 Sin[x (2 \[Pi] + z)]; 

ContourPlot[{ f == 0 , g == 0 , h == 0 }, {x, 0,5}, {y, 0, 3}, FrameLabel -> Automatic]
```

Comment: `f = -(-3 + x)^2 Cos[(2/3 + x) (π - y)] + 
   5 (1 + x)^2 Cos[(2/3 - x)] Sin[π (2/3 + x)];
g = -(3 + x)^2 Sin[π (2/3 + x)] Sin[(2/3 - x)] + 
   5 (-1 + x)^2 Sin[(2/3 + x) (π - y)];
h = 4 (-4 + x)^2 Cos[
     1/6 (π - 6 x z)] - (-4 + x^2)^2 (Sin[x (2 π - z)] + 
      2 Cos[2 x (π - y)]) + (5 + x^2)^2 Sin[x (2 π + z)];
Manipulate[
 ContourPlot[{f == 0, g == 0, h == 0 /. z -> c} // Evaluate, {x, 0, 
   5}, {y, 0, 3}, FrameLabel -> Automatic, 
  PerformanceGoal -> "Quality"], {c, 0, 5}]`

Answer (score 3):

One possibility is to make a slider for `z`

```
ClearAll[f, g, h, x, y, z];
f[x_, y_] := -(-3 + x)^2 Cos[(2/3 + x) (Pi - y)] + 5 (1 + x)^2 Cos[(2/3 - x)] Sin[Pi (2/3 + x)];
g[x_, y_] := -(3 + x)^2 Sin[Pi (2/3 + x)] Sin[(2/3 - x)] + 5*(-1 + x)^2 Sin[(2/3 + x) (Pi - y)];
h[x_, y_, z_] := 4 *(-4 + x)^2 Cos[1/6 (Pi - 6 x z)] - (-4 + x^2)^2 (Sin[x (2 Pi - z)] + 2 Cos[2 x (Pi - y)]) + (5 + x^2)^2 Sin[x (2 Pi + z)];

Manipulate[
 ContourPlot[{f[x, y] == 0, g[x, y] == 0, h[x, y, z] == 0}, 
          {x, 0, 5}, {y, 0, 3}, FrameLabel -> Automatic],

 {{z, 1, "z"}, 0, 5, .1, Appearance -> "Labeled"},

 TrackedSymbols :> {z}
 ]
```

[image]